# How can I get a floating help bubble or hint for a button in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

I am looking for a way to provide hint or help when a user hovers on a button. The button component does not have a hint like text components.

Comment: Does your request make sense only for desktops? In a touch-screen device, it's impossible to hover a button without pressing it.

Comment: Hmm. How do I implement the equivalent of tooltips in Codenameone on a touchscreen device?

Answer (score 1):

These are called tooltips and as Francesco explained they only make sense in a desktop app... Due to that there is no standard way of using them yet but we do support them and use them in our desktop apps.

E.g. this code is lifted directly from our GUI builder which is written in Codename One and features tooltips:

```
public static void setTooltip(Component cmp, String t) {
    cmp.putClientProperty("tooltip", t);
}

public static void showTooltip(Component cmp, Form f) {
    final String t = (String)cmp.getClientProperty("tooltip");
    if(t == null) {
        f.setGlassPane(null);
    } else {
        int offset = Display.getInstance().convertToPixels(2) + 10;
        final Font fnt = cmp.getUIManager().getComponentStyle("Label").getFont();
        int width = fnt.stringWidth(t);
        int height = fnt.getHeight();

        int x = cmp.getAbsoluteX();
        if(x > f.getWidth() / 2) {
            x -= (width + offset);
        } else {
            x += cmp.getWidth() + offset;
        }
        int y = cmp.getAbsoluteY();
        if(y > f.getHeight() / 2) {
            y -= (height + offset);
        } else {
            y += cmp.getHeight() + offset;
        }

        final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width + 10, height + 10);
        final Rectangle shadow = new Rectangle(x + 5, y + 5, width + 10, height + 10);
        final Stroke s = new Stroke(3, Stroke.CAP_ROUND, Stroke.JOIN_ROUND, 1);
        f.setGlassPane(new Painter() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle r) {
                g.setColor(0);
                g.setAlpha(120);
                g.fillShape(shadow);
                g.setAlpha(255);
                g.setColor(0xeeeeee);
                g.fillShape(rect);
                g.setColor(0);
                g.drawShape(rect, s);
                g.setColor(0);
                g.setFont(fnt);
                g.drawString(t, rect.getX()  + 5, rect.getY() + 5);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This code should be in a `Form` subclass:

```
@Override
public void pointerHover(int[] x, int[] y) {
    Component c = getComponentAt(x[0], y[0]);
    if(c != null) {
        GuiBuilderUtils.showTooltip(c, this);   
    }        
}
```

Comment: Will try this and see how it works in my use case. Thanks.